# Concanate cells from a column with respect to an indicator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

import pandas as pd

```
DataExe = [[2 , 1],
           [4 , 1],
           [7 , 2],
           [9 , 3],
           [10, 3],
           [15, 3],
           [19, 2],
           [24, 2],
           [27, 2],
           [29, 2],
           [37, 2],
           [38, 2]]


DataExe = pd.DataFrame(data = DataExe, columns = ['ColA', 'Indicator'])
```

What I am looking for is that the 'ColA' values are concented according to what 'Indicator' indicates. For example:

As it is observed in 'ColA' [2, 4] they have in common that 'Indicator' = 1. Then we create a new 'ColC' column where for each row place all the values of 'ColA'.

I must have the following:

```
ColA    Indicator   ColC
2       1           2, 4
4       1           2, 4
7       2           7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38
9       3           9, 10, 15
10      3           9, 10, 15
15      3           9, 10, 15
19      2           7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38
24      2           7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38
27      2           7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38
29      2           7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38
37      2           7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38
38      2           7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38
```

Note: ColC is a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby`+`transform`:

```
DataExe['ColC'] = DataExe.groupby('Indicator')['ColA'].transform(lambda g: ','.join(map(str, g)))
```

Output:

```
    ColA  Indicator                 ColC
0      2          1                  2,4
1      4          1                  2,4
2      7          2  7,19,24,27,29,37,38
3      9          3              9,10,15
4     10          3              9,10,15
5     15          3              9,10,15
6     19          2  7,19,24,27,29,37,38
7     24          2  7,19,24,27,29,37,38
8     27          2  7,19,24,27,29,37,38
9     29          2  7,19,24,27,29,37,38
10    37          2  7,19,24,27,29,37,38
11    38          2  7,19,24,27,29,37,38
```

Comment: Hi I have seen that you are very knowledgeable about pandas and data science. I couldn't find way to contact you privately. I am trying to make as many connections as I possibly can and learn from coders as I go along. If it is cool to personally message you about some questions please do let me know.

Comment: @georgehere do you have a specific question in mind? The best of usually to posts your questions here on SO, you'll benefit from everyone's expertise. If you really want, give me your email.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative that will return the groups of numbers as lists:

```
def GroupList(group):
    group['ColC'] = [np.array(group.ColA)]*len(group)
    return group

DataExe.groupby('Indicator').apply(GroupList)

Output:

   ColA Indicator   ColC
0   2   1   [2, 4]
1   4   1   [2, 4]
2   7   2   [7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38]
6   19  2   [7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38]
7   24  2   [7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38]
8   27  2   [7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38]
9   29  2   [7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38]
10  37  2   [7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38]
11  38  2   [7, 19, 24, 27, 29, 37, 38]
3   9   3   [9, 10, 15]
4   10  3   [9, 10, 15]
5   15  3   [9, 10, 15]
```

Or, more complicated syntax but in one line:

```
DataExe.groupby('Indicator').apply(lambda g:g.assign(ColC=[np.array(g.ColA)]*len(g))).droplevel(0)

    ColA    Indicator   ColC
0   2   1   [2 4]
1   4   1   [2 4]
2   7   2   [ 7 19 24 27 29 37 38]
6   19  2   [ 7 19 24 27 29 37 38]
7   24  2   [ 7 19 24 27 29 37 38]
8   27  2   [ 7 19 24 27 29 37 38]
9   29  2   [ 7 19 24 27 29 37 38]
10  37  2   [ 7 19 24 27 29 37 38]
11  38  2   [ 7 19 24 27 29 37 38]
3   9   3   [ 9 10 15]
4   10  3   [ 9 10 15]
5   15  3   [ 9 10 15]
```